# finding expression in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am beginner to python.I want to have a program which can go upto 20 and can show the expression only like `+,-` that can make number 10.

My expected output is:

```
20-10=10
8+2=10
6+4=10
```

I want to show them in list.

```
abc=[]
for x in range(1,20):
  for y in range(1,20):
    if x+y=10: 
       strValue=x+'+'+y 
       abc.append(strValue) 

    elif(x-y=10):
         strValue=x+'-'+y 
       abc.append(strValue) 

print(abc)
```

But,I get error

```
 at line 10
    abc.append(strValue)
    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: This line `strValue=x+'-'+y` is indented too far. change the indentation so it matches the next line.

Answer (score 2):

```
abc=[]
for x in range(1,20):
  for y in range(1,20):
    if x+y==10: 
       strValue=str(x)+'+'+str(y) 
       abc.append(strValue) 

    elif(x-y==10):
       strValue=str(x)+'-'+str(y) 
       abc.append(strValue) 

print(abc)
```

This edited code is working for me. The Indentation Error you are getting is because `abc.append(strValue)` is not indented correctly. Your indentation must be consistent throughout the scope (within the if statement), usually 4 spaces.

There were two other errors in your code stemming from the same problem.

You cannot concatenate an integer to a string like you did in `(x + '+' + y)`. You need to do `(str(x) + '+' + str(y))`

Also, in the if statements, you were using the wrong operator (= instead of the correct ==). = is the assignment operator used to set a value to a variable, whereas == compares two things.

Comment: I would suggest to have same indent, for `if` and `elif` part.

Comment: and also, it's not a must for `four-spaces` indent, it could be any number of spaces, but must be same in `same scope`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. you're right. i've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Python is an [Off-side rule language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-side_rule). It means that indentation is what will actually determine which part of the code belongs to the condition.

`IndentationError` means that you have problem with the indentation, and the interpreter should shows you the faulty line (or the line right after the faulty line, in this case).

Be sure to re-indent the line that starts with `strValue`.

---

Also:

1. Your conditions should use double-equal sign (`==`) to make a comparison, instead of one equal sign (`=`) which is usually used for assignment.
2. Cast integers to strings before concatenating them with other strings. You can use `str` to cast the integers explicitly, or fstrings to cast them implicitly (see code example below).

---

Code example (with some suggested improvements and stylefixes):

```
UPPER_CHECK_BOUND = 20
SOLUTION_TO_SEARCH_FOR = 10
valid_solutions = []

for x in range(1, UPPER_CHECK_BOUND):
    for y in range(1, UPPER_CHECK_BOUND):
        if x + y == SOLUTION_TO_SEARCH_FOR:
            exercise = f'{x} + {y}' 
            valid_solutions.append(exercise)
        elif x - y == SOLUTION_TO_SEARCH_FOR:
            exercise = f'{x} - {y}' 
            valid_solutions.append(exercise)

print(valid_solutions)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
abc=[]
for x in range(1,20):
  for y in range(1,20):
    if x+y=10: 
       strValue=x+'+'+y 
       abc.append(strValue) 

    elif(x-y=10):
         strValue=x+'-'+y # <= indent here is what cause error
       abc.append(strValue) 

print(abc)
```

Change it to

```
abc=[]
for x in range(1,20):
  for y in range(1,20):
    if x+y==10: #use == instead of =
       strValue=x+'+'+y 
       abc.append(strValue) 

    elif x-y == 10: # error with using = (use for assignment)
       strValue=x+'-'+y #two backspace solve problem
       abc.append(strValue) 

print(abc)
```

Comment: if x+y=10:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: edited! It should work for now.

Answer (score 0):

The line after `elif(x-y=10):` is indented too far, which is why there is an Indentation Error on the next line; the indentation isn't consistent. Match the indentation of `strValue=x+'-'+y` to the line after it:

```
abc=[]
for x in range(1,20):
  for y in range(1,20):
    if x+y=10: 
       strValue=x+'+'+y 
       abc.append(strValue) 

    elif(x-y=10):
       strValue=x+'-'+y 
       abc.append(strValue) 

print(abc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues in your code.

1. Python cares about spaces before the code on each line. Your indentation needs
       adjusting.
2. Your *if statements* are using the wrong operator. You're using the **assignment operator =** instead of the **comparison operator ==**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
abc = []
for x in range(1, 20):
    for y in range(1, 20):
        if x + y == 10:
            strValue = x + '+' + y
            abc.append(strValue)
        elif x - y == 10:

            strValue = x + '-' + y
            abc.append(strValue)

print abc
```

For indentation, you can use [an online tool like this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_python_formatter.htm) to get an idea of the correct format.

Comment: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'.